# How do I review a pull request in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: github, visual-studio-2019

Visual Studio 2019 normally has a [Team Explorer View](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/connect-team-project?view=vs-2019) with a Pull Requests button:

[image: Team Explorer]

But in My Visual Studio (Community version) this feature seems to be missing

Comment: This also can be caused by GitLab, I have gitLab and I do not have this feature as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Github integration comes with an extension. Can you try to install it from the marketplace ?

Link: [GitHub Extension for Visual Studio](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GitHub.GitHubExtensionforVisualStudio)

Comment: Note: Pull requests are not shown in the Team Explorer window until the '[New Git user experience](https://imgur.com/a/LQ1bBI3)' option is toggled off in Options.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio has a solid support for reviewing pull requests. There's good [article on Microsoft website](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/code-reviews-using-the-visual-studio-pull-requests-extension/) that explains it very well.

Install the extension from [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VSIDEVersionControlMSFT.pr4vs&ssr=false#overview).

[image]

Comment: Sadly, the extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VSIDEVersionControlMSFT.pr4vs&ssr=false#overview doesn't work with TFS (aka Azure DevOps Server). Still looking for other options. Would be open to using VS Code with extensions or even another Windows application, since no integration in VS 2019.