# How do I review a PR assigned to me in VS 2022

Tags: github, pull-request, visual-studio-2022

A team member has assigned me a large PR to review in our github repo.
I'd like to be able to review it/ comment on it / approve it from within Visual studio.

I am using VS 2022, in previous editions there was a PullRequest option in the github pane of the team explorer.  Thats gone away in 2022 and I cant find an option to work the PR assigned to me within the new VS ide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To further document the current state of affairs, here's some related info.

This feature used to exist under the extension [Pull Requests for Visual Studio](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VSIDEVersionControlMSFT.pr4vs) for VS 2019 as [announced in this blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/code-reviews-using-the-visual-studio-pull-requests-extension/). And the [GitHub Extension for Visual Studio](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GitHub.GitHubExtensionforVisualStudio) worked for VS 2015, 2017, and 2019.

Both extensions are still available to [view a pull request for **Visual Studio 2019**?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60109255/1366033)

The original extension was deprecated in 2021 and announced in the the post [Where Are My Favorite Extensions in Visual Studio 2022?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/where-are-my-favorite-extensions-in-visual-studio-2022/#from-extensions-to-integrated-vs-features) where it was announced that extension would now be a native feature within the IDE for VS 2022.

This feature comparison of the [Git experience to Team Explorer in Visual Studio 2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/version-control/git-team-explorer-feature-comparison?view=vs-2019) includes the side by side differences, but Pull Requests are noticeably absent from the comparisons.

Here's the current [marketing page for the github integration](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/github/) and [Visual Studio version control docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/version-control/?view=vs-2022).

The extension is currently developed in the [**github/VisualStudio**](https://github.com/github/VisualStudio) repo which currently has two open tickets requesting the feature:

- [**Issue #2634** · Will there be support for VS 2022 preview?](https://github.com/github/VisualStudio/issues/2634)
- [**Issue #2660** · Support VS2022](https://github.com/github/VisualStudio/issues/2660)

This has also spawned several requests in Microsoft's Developer Community feedback forums:

- [Full integration of Pull Requests in VS2022](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/VS2022-171-Git-Pull-Request-is-gone/1576559)
- [Bring all GitHub extension features to Visual Studio 2022](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Bring-all-GitHub-extension-features-to-V/10074172)
- [create and edit GitHub issues and Pull Requests](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/create-and-edit-GitHub-issues-and-Pull-R/10060891)

Interestingly, the documentation in the repo on [reviewing-a-pull-request-in-visual-studio.md](https://github.com/github/VisualStudio/blob/master/docs/using/reviewing-a-pull-request-in-visual-studio.md) does showcase the previous ability to view pull requests, but appears to be out of date, since the feature no longer works.

Alternatively, this feature *does* work in the [GitHub Pull Requests and Issues](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GitHub.vscode-pull-request-github) for **VS Code**, but not Visual Studio

### TLDR; This doesn't exist in VS 2022 today, but if you'd like to see it, go vote on those issues and feedback tickets

Answer (score 26):

This isn't currently available in Visual Studio 2022, even though Microsoft claims that all of the functionality from GitHub Extension for Visual Studio was incorporated into VS2022. The ability to view the list of pull requests and review them inside of VS2022 is not there.

We currently keep 2019 with the GitHub Extension for Visual Studio installed just to perform PR reviews because the GitHub web experience is relatively terrible for any non-trivial reviews, in our opinion.

Comment: Did you edit something to be able to install the extension in VS2022?

Comment: @JuanZamudio No, we were not able to install the extension in 2022 at all. This is why we have to keep 2019 hanging around, unfortunately.

Comment: Can we test a PR in VS2022 with DevOps?

Answer (score 1):

New Relic has the extension [CodeStream](https://newrelic.com/codestream) for VS Code and Visual Studio.

VS Code New Relic CodeStream extension is light and fast. It has all the functionality that I liked in Visual Studio 2019 GitHub extension, plus more!

Visual Studio 2022 New Relic extension is more like GitHub Web UI is integrated into the Visual Studio Tab. It's slow and it keeps adding some JSON schema to our solution folder.

Comment: Is it free? It seems like it's part of a bundle and you have to buy the entire bundle, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I've been using "GitHub Requests and Issues" by GitHub extension for VS Code but I didn't find anything for VS 2022 yet and I'm using GitHub web interface for now.